# How do I change String Objects daily in Express/Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, cron, schedule

As title states I have 6 string objects that I would like to update daily at midnight within Node.JS. One is a regular string and the other is an array of strings.

I know this isn't natively supported in NodeJS so I had looked into Node-Scheduler and Cron Jobs but they didn't look to do exactly what I needed.

Let's say today, March 3rd I want

```
let answer = "Bill Gates"
```

and tomorrow March 4th I want

```
let answer = "Elon Musk"
```

is there a way to do this?

Comment: 1. Put the string in an object in a module. 2. Import the module wherever you want to use it (this includes the cron job). 3. Update the value of the string every midnight (eg: `myModule.answer = "Elon Musk"`). That's it. This works as long as you're running only one process (not load balanced between multiple servers, not running a cluster etc.). Modules in node (both ES6 and CJS) are proper singletons and behave like singleton objects. If you update a value exported by a module it will be updated globally everywhere it is imported as long as you don't destructure  the import.

Comment: ... Destructuring the import (eg. `import {answer} from 'MyModule'`) will copy the string to the variable instead of holding a reference. Instead import the entire module as an object since objects are references (eg. `import * as myModule from 'MyModule'`)